# AWS cloudfront httpOnly cookie not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, cookie-httponly

I am trying to create a simple website experience using aws cloudfront, s3, api gateway, lambda authorizer, cognito identity pool and lambda functions.

I have an index.html and related script.js at s3 bucket. I have configured cloudfront to host the index.html
Index.html has a form which takes username password and the javascript send the details to API gateway. There is a lambda handler defined for API gateway resource /signin which received the username password and authenticate that with cognito identity pool. On successful login, the lambda handler sends the auth token as Set-Cookie along with the response. The response body is an HTML which has a clickable button and embedded script. On clicking the button the script send a GET request to API gateway resource /invenory.
[Origin request policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdaZR.png)

[Response header policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ZTx.png)

**The problem statement:**
The GET request to /inventory ideally carry the auth token returned by the previous /signin POST request but that's not happening.

**Question**
Can you suggest what changes should be done so that while using the cloudfront, httpOnly cookie is sent along with subsequent call automatically?

**Observation:**
When I use developers tool to see the returned response,
I see the response header of POST request to /signin has the auth token in network tab. But when I go to application tab to look for the cookie, I don't find the cookie and looks like that's why auth token is not send along with subsequent GET request.

Also observed if I use the API gateway link like https://abcd.i.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Dev/signin then response header has the auth token as well as application tab shows the httpOnly cookie also.

Comment: Have you checked if the cache policy on the cache behavior serving this request is forwarding that cookie to your origin? CloudFront requires that you specify the headers, query strings, and cookies you want to forward to your origin by adding it to your cache policy (which adds to your cache key).

Comment: Added the origin request policy and response header policy details. Can you check and comment on the policies?

Comment: What happened when you made that change? You should put the cookie in the cache policy since it is specific to individual user sessions. When you move to a cache policy, you should also specify the individual values to be part of your cache key rather than using "All" if you only need specific values.

Comment: I did this policy creation before posting this issue. The observation and everything with these policies.